# How to update paperclip video location after processing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip for processing a user uploaded video with ffmpeg.  I want to create a thumbnail image as well as convert the video to a standard format of my choosing.  I have the ffmpeg processing working, however, I can't seem to figure out how to update the record after it has finished processing.  I've used a number of rails - paperclip - ffmpeg references but haven't seen anyone converting the video and then using the converted video in the rails db, since it's creating a new video I will need to be able to update the record from within the paperclip processor, but how to do it??

Thanks

- using Rails 3
- using paperclip processor with ffmpeg

Comment: Can you show us your processor code? Have you considered using an existing gem such as [paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation for [Paperclip::Processor](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.4.3/Paperclip/Processor):

> There is only one method you must implement to properly be a subclass [of
>   `Paperclip::Processor`]: `#make`...
>
> All `#make` needs to return is an instance of `File` (`Tempfile` is acceptable)
>   which contains the results of the processing.

So your Processor would look something like this:

```
module Paperclip
  class MyProcessor
    # ...

    def make file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      in_filename = File.absolute_path file.path  # probably just a good idea

      out_filename = 'output_filename.mp4' # doesn't matter, maybe you use
                                           # Tempfile--just need to know
                                           # the path of ffmpeg's output file
      # run ffmpeg
      self.class.run 'ffmpeg',
        "-i #{in_filename}", /* more params..., */ out_filename

      File.open out_filename, 'r'  # then just return a File object pointing to
    end                            # the output file; Paperclip does the rest
  end
end
```